# Sending authorization token header through Python requests

Tags: python, api, authorization, python-requests, token

I'm trying to use an API, which requires an authorization token, with the requests library for Python 2.7.  The API documentation provides example code for curl:

```
curl <url> \
  -is \
  -X GET \
  -H 'Accept: application/vnd.rn+json' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/vnd.rn+json' \
  -H 'Authorization: Token token="<hexstring>"'
```

How would I go about converting this into the correct syntax for Requests, and checking the status?  I've tried a few things, none of which have worked:

```
import requests
url = '<url>'
header = {'Authorization':'<hexstring>'}
r = requests.get(url,header)
print r.status_code
```

and

```
import requests
url = '<url>'
token = '<hexstring>'
header = {'Authorization':token}
r = requests.get(url,header)
print r.status_code
```

and even

```
import requests
url = '<url>'
header = {'Authorization':'Authorization: Token token="<hexstring>"'}
r = requests.get(url,header)
print r.status_code
```

Everything keeps returning a 401 status, so the token isn't going through right.  Any ideas on how to do this properly?  Thanks.

Edit: I suppose I should add - the token I'm using is correct, so that's not the issue.

Comment: Have you added the other headers (Accept & Content-Type)? The server might not like your request the way it is given. I think you should try `header = {'Authorization':'Token token="<hexstring>"'}` as well.

Comment: I added the other headers as well as making the headers an argument in the requests.get.  Now I'm getting a 500 error - I'll have to email them.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the AWS API Gateway, the Authorization header must have "Bearer" followed by one space.  Here is an example for a "GET" request.  A POST will require a body in the request.  You might also need to add headers for

- Accept: application/json
- Content-Type: application/json

---

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import requests

api_name = "my_api"
amazon_region = "us-east-1"
url = f"https://{api_name}.execute-api.{amazon_region}.aws.com/Prod"

token = "some-long-string"
headers = {"Authorization": f"Bearer {token}"}

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print(r.json())
```